# Error:(27,0) android studio error

Tags: java, android, junit

Gradle sync failed: Supplied String module notation 'com.android.support:appcompat  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12.
This is the error I'm getting and here is my build.gradle(Module app) code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.honey.hello"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat  testCompile \'junit:junit:4.12\'-v7:24.2.1'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line
From:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat  testCompile \'junit:junit:4.12\'-v7:24.2.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Then Sync your Gradle, it will be fixed